# addClass, removeClass, preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to removeClass "active" form all childelements and addCLass "active" to one childelement, but when I use event.preventDefault,the link in the element will not longer work, if I remove the event.preventDefault, the addClass will work only in very short time and it will go back to the default "active" class. The html code:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="">m1</a></li>
        <li ><a href="/something/">m2</a></li>
        <li ><a href="/anotherThing/">m3</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#aboutUs">m4</a></li>
        <li ><a href="">m5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menubar li").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#menubar li").removeClass("active")
        $(this).addClass("active")

    });  
})
```

what should I do to enable the links?

Comment: when a page is loaded you need to set the active class accordingly

Comment: So you want it to AND load the page AND set the class active?

Comment: the class is set to active, but the link is prevent work, I want to set active class to the clicked element and working link to the clicked element

Comment: Well, that is not possible in this way, you either have to use AJAX to load your content or go with what @ArunPJohny said.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in .Net you could create navagation bar using a menu object in the master page and add this to the code behind

```
string ThisPage = Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath;

 foreach (MenuItem item in Menu1.Items)
 {
    if (item.NavigateUrl == ThisPage)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
        item.Selectable = true;
    }
}

foreach (MenuItem item in MenuAdmin.Items)
{
    if (item.NavigateUrl == ThisPage)
    {
         item.Selected = true;
         item.Selectable = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the backend to set this in order for it to 'stick'. Otherwise following a link resets the javascript.

Comment: I shudder to suggest this but you could loop through each menu item and set its active class based on location.href

Comment: Alternatively, you could $.get () the href s content and load it into your content div asynchronously avoiding the page reload.

Comment: can you enlighten me a bit more?

Comment: Setting the active class using javascript will only set that class while you are on the same page. As soon as you leave the page, the javascript will get refreshed, meaning that it will re-bind the function but does not remember the previous state. Whatever is responsible for rendering the page with the menu should be responsible for setting the active class. Or you could do `$("#menubar").find("li a").each(function (){if ($(this).attr('href') == location.href){ $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); } })` or something like that.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add to your current click method `$.get($(this).find('a').attr('href'), function(data){$("#contentDivOfSomeSort").html(data);});` which will load the clicked page into a div with the id 'contentDivOfSomeSort' and not cause the refresh.